# How to to move axes to the border of the figures?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a chart with the code below

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(rc={'axes.facecolor':'white','grid.color': '#b0b0b0','axes.edgecolor': 'black','figure.edgecolor':'black'})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10),linewidth=5, edgecolor="black",facecolor="orange")
gridShape=(25,6)
primaryFontSize = 15
secondaryFontSize = 12
smallFontSize = 10
topHeaderRowSpan=2
infoRowSpan=1
mainChartRowspan = 17
footerStartRow = mainChartRowspan+4

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (0,0), colspan=1, rowspan=infoRowSpan)
ax1.text(0.5, 0.5, 'ABC', va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (0,1), colspan=1, rowspan=infoRowSpan)
ax2.text(0.5, 0.5, 'DEF', va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)
ax3  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (0,2), colspan=2, rowspan=topHeaderRowSpan)
ax3.text(0.5, 0.5, 'GHI', va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=primaryFontSize)
ax4  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (0,4), colspan=1, rowspan=topHeaderRowSpan)
ax4.text(0.5, 0.5, 'JKL' , va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=primaryFontSize)
ax5  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (0,5), colspan=1, rowspan=topHeaderRowSpan)
ax5.text(0.5, 0.5, 'MON', va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)
ax6 = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (1,0), colspan=1, rowspan=infoRowSpan)
ax6.text(0.5, 0.5, 'PQR', va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)
ax7 = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (1,1), colspan=1, rowspan=infoRowSpan)
ax7.text(0.5, 0.5, 'STU', va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)

plotAxis = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (3, 0), colspan=6, rowspan=mainChartRowspan)

ax9  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (footerStartRow+1,0), colspan=1, rowspan=3)
ax9.text(0.5, 0.5, 'VWX', va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=primaryFontSize)
ax10  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (footerStartRow+1,1), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
ax10.text(0.5, 0.5, 'XYZ', va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)
ax11  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (footerStartRow+2,1), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
ax11.text(0.5, 0.5, 'ABC', va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)
ax12  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (footerStartRow+3,1), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
ax12.text(0.5, 0.5, 'DEF', va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)


ax13  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (footerStartRow+1,2), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
ax13.text(0.5, 0.5, 'GHI' , va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)
ax14  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (footerStartRow+2,2), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
ax14.text(0.5, 0.5, 'JKL' , va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)
ax15  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (footerStartRow+3,2), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
ax15.text(0.5, 0.5, 'MNO' , va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)

ax16  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (footerStartRow+1,3), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax16.text(0.5, 0.5, 'PQR' , va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)
ax17  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (footerStartRow+2,3), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax17.text(0.5, 0.5, 'GHRHRHRRHRHR' , va="center", ha="center",fontsize=smallFontSize)

ax18  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (footerStartRow+1,5), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
ax18.text(0.5, 0.5, 'STU', va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)
ax19  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (footerStartRow+2,5), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax19.text(0.5, 0.5, 'XYZ' , va="center", ha="center" , fontsize=secondaryFontSize)

axesList = [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5,ax6,ax7,ax9,ax10,ax11,ax12,ax13,ax14,ax15,ax16,ax17,ax18,ax19]
for a in axesList:
    a.set_xticklabels([])
    a.set_yticklabels([])
    a.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    a.yaxis.set_visible(False)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace =0, hspace =0)
```

The saved picture looks like so.

[image]

There is too much gap on the outside (shown by Red Arrows). How to remove this gap?
Even with the gap shown in RED arrows is made to zero, there may still be some gaps (shown in Blue arrows) since the space is need to X-Axis ticks. In that case, how to stretch the axes itself so that they touch the border?

In the end, I am looking to have picture like this. Is this even possible, if yes, how.

[image]

Comment: I admire your tireless pursuit. I have tried running your code in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jfGvcD24h2GiqSYhIB5z0pM_0ys7-Gat?usp=sharing). The result is that I get the result with the gaps in the question removed. Is this a difference in the execution environment? If you check Colab, I will disable the link.

Comment: I am running the code on my machine (colab is not an option for me). I create a environment in conda & then run the script. I ran it with Jupyter Notebook & directly. Same result both times. There is gap as shown in the picture in the question.

Comment: I tried it in my environment before creating it in Colab. There were no gaps, so I experimented with Colab to share and got similar results, which is why I commented. My environment is jupyterlab:3.4.3 I disabled the Colab link.

Comment: There are no gaps even when the plot is saved? I ask because when the run in Jupyter notebook, the plot displayed in-line (similar to colab) has small gaps but the saved pic has too much gap. Gap is there nonetheless.

Comment: I added the following settings when saving and checked the saved file. Gaps are minimized. `plt.savefig(r"/content/template.jpg", bbox_inches='tight')`

Comment: Yes, things did improve. But as you said, gaps still exist :-( It there no way to move the axes itself to the border? Thanks anyway for looking into this.